# Coluna id com primary key e auto increment está retornando null MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, pdo, auto-incremento

Boa noite galera, é o seguinte, tenho uma aplicação que estava funcionando até esses dias, ai hoje quando fui adicionar um post no banco de dados, minha id_post que é Primary Key e Auto_increment não está sendo adicionada, retorna o erro que minha id_post não pode ser null

aqui está a imagem do erro no banco

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aqui está a tabela no banco de dados

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
 `id_post` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_pergunta` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `texto` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
 `id_user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `data` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_post`),
 KEY `fk_per_post` (`id_pergunta`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_per_post` FOREIGN KEY (`id_pergunta`) REFERENCES `pergunta` 
(`id_per`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Aqui a função php para adicinar no banco

```
function Postar($post){
          $comando = $this->prepare("INSERT INTO posts 
(id_pergunta,texto,id_user,nome,,data)
                                   VALUES (?,?,?,?,now())");

        try{$comando->execute($post);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            $this->Mensagem = $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }

    }
```

E aqui o codigo php que envia para a função adicionar no banco

```
$texto = $_POST["textoresposta"];
$user = $_SESSION["usuario"];
$usuario = $_SESSION["usuario.nome"];
$pergunta = $_POST["idpergunta"];
$comentarioid = $_POST["id_comentario"];
$textocomentario = $_POST["textocomentario"];

    //Aqui fazemos o registro da opnião sobre a pergunta
$postDAO = new PostDAO();
if ($texto == ""){
    echo "<h3>Você tem que escrever alguma coisa</h3>";
}else{
    $postar = array($pergunta,$texto,$user,$usuario);
    $sucesso = $postDAO->Postar($postar);
    if($sucesso){
        header("Location: feed.php");
        exit();
    }else{
        header("Location: index.php?erro=". $postDAO->Mensagem);
    }

}
```

Não estou entendo porque a coluna id_post está retornando null se é um auto incremento, se alguem puder me ajudar por favor seria otimo.

Comment: Coloque o código em vez de imagens.

Comment: Kkk parece até coisa combinada (não fosse o fato da resposta estar errada), pq um coloca "Quem vigia os vigilantes" na pergunta e o RORSHACH que responde...

Comment: ai @sam na real, coloquei as fotos pq sao varios codigos, e ficaria mais facil de compreender. vlw bolsominon

Comment: @Bacco achei incrivel isso tbm, assustado.

Comment: @BrunoClementin não vai mesmo corrigir a postagem? Desse jeito que tá não fica legal pra quem for testar nem analisar, mal dá pra ler, tem que ficar ampliando e arrastando imagem, e quem está usando por mobile praticamente não vê o post direito. Se copiar e colar do seu editor, facilita pra todo mundo (e tem um botão de formatação de código, o botão { } da barrinha , ou tecla control K, basta selecionar o trecho de código desejado e acionar o atalho)

Comment: @Bacco desculpa, eu cometi uma grande erro :/

Comment: @RORSCHACH não tem pq pedir desculpas, eu só avisei pq nao ia adiantar nada o post com informação incorreta.

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/83882

Comment: @RORSCHACH mas se vc conseguir localizar o problema pode editar e restaurar seu post depois, imagino que vc já saiba disso (deve ter a ver com um nulo numa coluna que não aceita nulo, pelo que mal dá pra ver na 1a imagem)

Comment: @Bacco com uma explicação dessa logico que eu mudo.

Comment: Já melhora muito com o PHP, se quiser fazer o mesmo na parte SQL, tem um jeito fácil no PHPMyADMIN, que é entrar na aba SQL e executar `SHOW CREATE TABLE redesocial.posts;` ai a estrutura vem em SQL prontinha pra copiar e colar (ai a gente pode até executar num SQL Fiddle pra testar, por exemplo).

Comment: Bruno, Você notou que tem um `,,` sobrando em `(id_pergunta,texto,id_user,nome,,data)`?

Comment: galera resolvi aqui, muito obrigado pelas informações mais era um parametro  errado no name do form, achei aqui vlws e vou fazer esse lance do sql @Bacco

Comment: @BrunoClementin coloque a solução que você encontrou, talvez sirva de ajuda caso alguém passe pelo mesmo problema

Answer (score 0):

A solução é apenas um parametro errado no form, ele estava assim

```
<div id="posts">    
    <form action="post_grava.php" method="post" id="publicar">
        <input type="hidden" name="idpergunta" value="<?=$pergunta["id_per"];?>"/>
        <textarea class='autoExpand' rows="1" data-min-rows='1' placeholder="O que você pensa sobre isso?" id="textoresposta" name="textocomentario"
            <?php     if(!isset($_SESSION["usuario"]) || !isset($_SESSION["usuario.nome"])) 
            { ?>
            onclick="$('#login').fadeIn(); $('#publicar').hide();" <?php } ?>></textarea> 

          <?php if(isset($_SESSION["usuario"]) || isset($_SESSION["usuario.nome"])) {?>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Publicar"/>
         <?php } ?>

    </form>         
</div>
```

no name do form está name="textocomentario" e o correto é name="textoresposta".
problema corrido